# Can someone explain this joke?

Tags: jokes

> So I went to the watch shop. I said, "I wanna buy a watch".
> He said "Analogue?"
> I said, "No, just the watch".

Comment: Comments have been locked because answers have been misposted in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pun.

"analogue" is a kind of watch -- the kind with moving hands, as opposed to a digital watch that displays the time numerically.

"analogue" also sounds like "and a log" -- in many accents, the "d" of "and" is not emphasized.

So the customer is responding to the question "And a log?", rather than the type of watch he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Formalizing Henry's comment as an answer:
Analogue sounds like "and a log". The customer wants a watch rather than both a watch and a log.